# Locked out of PHPMyAdmin with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I use CakePHP with Xampp on OSX and recently installed wordpress for the first time. I changed some passwords, which I didn't realize would affect PHPMyAdmin. Upon trying to go to localhost/phpmyadmin I'm prompted with a login screen. I wrote down the password and username that I changed, and still, it won't allow me in. I get the following error

```
Authentication required!

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL "/phpmyadmin". You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
```

I've tried doing [what this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574568/changed-password-in-phpmyadmin-on-a-mac-using-xampp-now-unable-to-access-localh) but it didn't work.

This is the contents of my config.inc.php file

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
#$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
# commented out by xampp security
#$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
#$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';
```

I even tried re-installing XAMPP. I've cleared my browser history between every change I made.

Comment: Did you try username `root` with no password?

Comment: I've tried just about every "default" username and password combo. root:null, root:password, admin:password,daemon:password,nobody:xampp, etc...

Comment: An easy was is to reset the password using 'sudo xampp security' command, [youtube - tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHvNFZoWp_I)

Answer (score 5):

In your config.inc.php, replace

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

with

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Then you'll get the "normal" phpMyAdmin login screen (with the sailboat logo).

Comment: Saved my butt for an assignment today, thanks! Had to use a combination of this answer and @staphreak answer to fix it

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.inc.php` file notice the following(line 21 for me):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

if you enter password here and restart MySQL via the admin panel, you should be able to get in, it worked for me anyway.