# Unable to access phpMyAdmin after changing password on mac OS

Tags: macos, xampp

I've changed my password in phpMyAdmin on mac OS through XAMPP, however now I'm getting access denied when I try to access phpMyAdmin. It says "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

I've looked into solutions for this (like [Changed password in phpMyAdmin on a Mac using XAMPP, now unable to access localhost/phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574568/changed-password-in-phpmyadmin-on-a-mac-using-xampp-now-unable-to-access-localh)), however they all reference a config.inc.php file which I don't seem to have on my computer upon XAMPP's installation. I've looked for that file in my Mac's Library, as well as in Applications/XAMPP. There just doesn't seem to be any PHP My Admin installation file.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to mount the folder within the program's UI.